# Why AWS Lambda eating all my assigned storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have more than 100 lambda function in my account. Recently, I visit the Lambda dashboard there I see Lambda Code Storage has crossed 75GBs which is very unexpected.
[image: Lambda Storage]

I checked all my Lambda function's code storage one by one. None of my Lambda crossed even 50MB then why it is so high? Is there anything else that is eating all that storage. I also checked Lambda Layers and no layer exceeds 60MBs. It is very disturbing for me. Can someone guide me here please or is there anything I am missing out ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Published versions of the Lambda function consume code storage and published versions of Lambda layers.

So, in your case, the Lambda layer has 60MB, but if you have 10 versions of it, it would consume 600 MB. Same with Lambda functions. You should check for old, unneeded versions of your Lambda functions and layers, and clean that up.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I somehow got the answer earlier but you are right. Thanks.